# Software Installation (CoreBoot flashrom) on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, compiling

I am starting to learn flashing roms. Downloaded "flashrom.tar.gz" from here https://review.coreboot.org/cgit/flashrom.git/snapshot/flashrom-p1.0.tar.gz . Unable to understand how to install this package. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please confirm release - there is no January release of Ubuntu; there is only 17.04 (2017.April) which is now EOL, and 17.10 (2017.October).  tar.gz is a tarball (gzipped). The gz is compression method, and tar tells us it's more than a single file combined into one file. You expand the file & follow instructions usually found in the README, or INSTALL  text file.

Comment: Thnx guiverc .. the ubuntu version is 17.10 .. and even after uncompressing i cant find the INSTALL file in the package README  is there but confusing .. checked some internet resources but still in a fix

Comment: if you found INSTALL it'd be the same as README.  The format is from the 1970s (well before linux) where most people that used it were technical in nature, and its platform independent meaning the same will work for unix, GNU/Linux, dos, windoze, osx & other environments. It's usually related to source that is compiled (with `make` assuming build tools are already present  `sudo apt install build-essential`).  This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/1966/is-there-any-simple-way-to-install-tarballs but given the specialist nature it may be slightly different).

Answer (score 0):

You should install build-essential and dependencies with:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpci-dev libusb-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev \ 
libftdi-dev linux-headers-generic
```

Then download, extract and compile your application:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://review.coreboot.org/cgit/flashrom.git/snapshot/flashrom-p1.0.tar.gz
tar -xf flashrom-p1.0.tar.gz
cd flashrom-p1.0/
make
```

After compilation you will find `flashrom` executable in the current directory, it produces the following output:

```
$./flashrom 
flashrom  on Linux 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at https://flashrom.org

Please select a programmer with the --programmer parameter.
Previously this was not necessary because there was a default set.
To choose the mainboard of this computer use 'internal'. Valid choices are:
internal, dummy, nic3com, nicrealtek, gfxnvidia, drkaiser, satasii, atavia,
it8212, ft2232_spi, serprog, buspirate_spi, dediprog, rayer_spi, pony_spi,
nicintel, nicintel_spi, nicintel_eeprom, ogp_spi, satamv, linux_spi,
usbblaster_spi, pickit2_spi, ch341a_spi.
```