# I have installed one software Anyconnect-predeploy-linux-3.1.04072-k9.tar but I can not see them inside my installed software

Tags: 14.04, 18.04

I have installed one software Anyconnect-predeploy-linux-3.1.04072-k9.tar but I can not see them inside my installed software. May be that is why I can not open it. Could you please instruct me what should I do ? I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any simple way to install tarballs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1966/is-there-any-simple-way-to-install-tarballs)

Comment: You've listed a file (generally called a tarball); these are usually expanded & compiled.  By installed software what do you mean?  Package management tools generally work with debs (some show snaps too), which won't show tarball or manually added software, but do you mean doesn't show in menu? or please be more specific.  Many tarballs don't add menu items, you do it yourself or run it from term.  *You should also explain why you've also tagged off-topic 14.04*

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't get your point. After installing I can see the logo(if I search it by name) of it but If I click it it is not opening. Again If I go to the installed software then I can not find it anymore.