# Install zip file

Tags: software-installation, zip

I'm a student of homeopathy. I need to install a homeopathy software OpenRep SYNOPSIS. The file is in zip file. Could anyone guide me on how to  install the software? Thanks.
Here is the link https://www.homeopathyonline.org/download.php

Comment: zip is an archive format (same as gz, bz etc) which has no installation standard having existed from the late 1980s with many many standards on how files are installed post-extraction. The instructions will either be found where the file was obtained; OR when the archive is expanded within it (in an INSTALL or README type of doc).  The packager/creator of the archive decides which standard they wish to follow; and we can't help as we don't know what Ubuntu product, release or clear details as to what & where you obtained it from

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any simple way to install tarballs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1966/is-there-any-simple-way-to-install-tarballs)

Comment: Please don't install this, It is made for Ubuntu 12.04  That is 11 years old. Not going to work

Comment: If you are intending to buy a license, since they are still accepting money for their software, and a lot at that, I would write to their contact email address `info@homeopathyonline.org` and ask them why they have not updated the software for so many years. They also have a blog. Their domain `http://instituteforhomoeopathicmedicine.org/` has also been suspended. I know this is out of the scope of Ask Ubuntu but I'm mentioning it as a friend. If you are just going to use the demo version, we'll try to get it to work.

Comment: For now I'm using demo version for windows using wine. I ll purchase premium version in next semester. Can't afford now. I am grateful to everybody who offered me help in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install ZIP files. You extract them. `unzip` it, check the content and ...

- make sure it is an Ubuntu supported content. (Generally Linux content is available as a `tar.gz` and not a zip file. `tar.gz` can hold user permissions; `zip` tends to be Windows but there are exceptions.)
- find a readme.txt, or install.txt
- view the contents using any of the tools to view textfiles (`cat`, `more`, `vi`, or a graphical tool)
- and follow those instructions.

If there is no text file or you can see an executable with a name explaining what it is execute that. It might need a `chmod 700 {file}` to be able to do that.

If there is nothing to execute it might be that you need to open the `zip` from a software and that software then handles everything for you. Not often this happens though.

All generic this: if you need a more detailed answer provide a link to the file please.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Here is the link https://www.homeopathyonline.org/download.php

Comment: That link should be in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular application:

Make sure you have Oracle Java 8 Runtime or newer equivalent installed on your system.

Download the Linux version and unpack (extract) the .zip file to a folder of your choice (for example, create a folder called "Homeopathy" in your home directory.

Look for a file called `start.jar`

Right click and open with Oracle Java 8 Runtime

It will run the program and guide you through the steps.

This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.2 with Java Runtime 8 but as mentioned above, it was created in 2011 so there might be security issues.

[image: start.jar]

Comment: Thanks for responding. But no such options are coming after installing Oracle 20.

Comment: @AtanuSarkarwhat happens if you right click on `start.jar` ? Since it is an old program, you might have to install an earlier version of Oracle Runtime

Comment: My bad. I think I need to install JRE not JDK

Comment: You need JRE 1.6 acc. to the contents. That one is dead and buried almost a decade ago.

Comment: would openJDK work?

Comment: Use `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre` it works on my machine with this version.

Comment: Installed but unable to open the file.

Comment: try run `OpenRep.jar` then. It will complain that there is not enough memory, but just click on continue.